# /iu:/ and /ju:/ sound differences?

Tags: pronunciation

How community  /kəˈmjuːnəti/ can have j inside it ? And I have struggled with it for last night. According to what i have researched, /j/ is equals /i:/ but faster. I try to pronounce beautiful slow mo but still can’t find where does the /j/ sound take part in, more like a /i:u/ sound